# SSH to localhost server

Tags: ssh, sshd, openssh

I have ArchLinux (kernel 4.8.4-1) machine which I try to turn into SSH server. For the last few days I've been struggling with getting it to work. I have read loads of articles, tutorials and other stuff like this but all of them look the same and none solves my problem.

After running

```
$ssh -vvv alagris@Oelkozadam
```

I get:

```
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/alagris/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/alagris/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for Oelkozadam
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "oelkozadam" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to oelkozadam [192.168.7.145] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/alagris/.ssh/test type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alagris/.ssh/test-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to oelkozadam:22 as 'alagris'
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nist    p521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,dif    fie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openss    h.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.    com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed2551    9,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.c    om,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.c    om,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sh    a2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,h    mac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sh    a2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,h    mac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nist    p521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,dif    fie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.c    om,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.c    om,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sh    a2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,h    mac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sh    a2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,h    mac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:LOy/ttmSoIpf6+H0jRYCVveaNrhjTRDV61fCx6CQxQ4
The authenticity of host 'oelkozadam (192.168.7.145)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:LOy/ttmSoIpf6+H0jRYCVveaNrhjTRDV61fCx6CQxQ4.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'oelkozadam,192.168.7.145' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/alagris/.ssh/test (0x55ad2b5b8360), explicit, agent
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 53
debug3: input_userauth_banner
Welcome to Oelkozadam's remote workstation. Intruders are not so welcome.
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/alagris/.ssh/test
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

These are the permissions:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown alagris:users ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I have generated keys with this command:

```
ssh-keygen -b 3072 -f "~/.ssh/$key" -P "$pass" -C "$(whoami)@$(hostname)-$(date -I)"
```

and used cat to append public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

~/.ssh/config looks as follows:

```
Host Oelkozadam
   IdentitiesOnly yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/test
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config looks as follows:

```
Port 22
AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 192.168.7.145
AllowUsers remote_user alagris
PermitRootLogin no
Banner /my/config/SSH_ServerBanner
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
AuthorizedKeysFile      ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server    
PrintMotd no
```

"$systemctl edit sshd.socket" looks as follows:

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=
ListenStream=22
```

I have no idea what else I could to make it work. I also tried to SSH from my Mac laptop via LAN but I get similar results.

(edit:I removed all files in ~/.ssh and generated test and test.pub from scratch, added test.pub to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys,once again set permissions on all these files, rebooted computer, ran

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/test
```

and connected again. The output slightly changed. Now it says:

```
Offering RSA public key: /home/alagris/.ssh/test
```

The previous:

```
Offering RSA public key: /my/config/SSH/test
```

was probably fault of some unapplied changes which got updated after reboot.
Also, an interesting fact is that as I recreated authorized_keys file, the key that I generated for my Mac computer was lost and yet the output of ssh connection is absolutely the same. It's very similar to output on local machine but the end:

```
send packet: type 50 
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply 
debug3: receive packet: type 51 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey 
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/alagris/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug3: no such identity: /Users/alagris/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory 
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/alagris/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug3: no such identity: /Users/alagris/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory 
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/alagris/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug3: no such identity: /Users/alagris/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory 
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method 
debug1: No more authentication methods to try. 
Permission denied (publickey).
```

)

PS. I wish I could see any logs coming directly from server but it seems on ArchLinux there are no files like /var/log/auth.log. I can olny view journalctl which seems to be quite empty.

Comment: this line looks very suspicious to me debug1: Offering RSA public key: /my/config/SSH/test

Comment: What about server log? It is helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what happened. I kind of gave up but then after a few reboots it just magically started working.

Answer (score 4):

according to your .ssh/config

> ~/.ssh/config looks as follows:

```
Host Oelkozadam
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/test
```

you use `~/.ssh/test` as private key, is the corresponding public key listed in the `authorized_keys` file ?

Also, you mention a password :

> I have generated keys with this command:

```
ssh-keygen -b 3072 -f "~/.ssh/$key" -P "$pass" -C "$(whoami)@$(hostname)-$(date -I)"
```

is this key loaded (using `ssh-add`) ?

So check that

1. public part of `~/.ssh/test` is in authorized_keys
2. `~/.ssh/test` is loaded (use `ssh-add -l` )